# Linked lists, operations with parameter

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to implement program in with i can create ~arbitrary number of singly linked lists dynamically and perform operations on particular one (defined by parameter). I create dynamic array of head pointers so that i can refer to the certain head node defined by paramater(index of an array + 1). Parameter is just (1,2,3..number of lists). So far I have managed to implement only initialise and push function but the program after complilation doesn't work as expected. Where is the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define CHUNK 10

typedef struct
{
    char *str;
    struct node *next;
} node;


node *initialise(node **array, int *amount_of_lists);
void push(node **array, int *amount_of_lists);
char *getString(void);

int main()
{
    node **heads = NULL; //initially null, pointer to the dynamic array of head pointers
    int amount_of_lists = 0;
    int *no_of_heads = &amount_of_lists;

    initialise(heads, no_of_heads);
    initialise(heads, no_of_heads);
    push(heads, no_of_heads);
    push(heads, no_of_heads);

    return 0;
}

node *initialise( node **array, int *amount_of_lists )  /*reallocate memory for another head pointer ans return the pointer to node*/
{
    ++(*amount_of_lists);
    printf("\n%d", *amount_of_lists);
    array = (node**)realloc(array, sizeof(node*)*(*amount_of_lists));
    return array[(*amount_of_lists) - 1] = malloc(sizeof(node));
}

int readParameter(int *amount_of_lists)
{
    int parameter = 0, control = 0;
    bool repeat = 0;
    do
    {
        if(repeat)
        {
            printf("\nWrong parameter, try again.");
        }
        printf("\n Enter list parameter: ");
        control = scanf("%d", &parameter);
        fflush(stdin);
        repeat = 1;
    }
    while( control != 1 || parameter < 1 || parameter > (*amount_of_lists) );

    return parameter;
}

void push(node **array, int *amount_of_lists)
{
    int parameter = readParameter(amount_of_lists) - 1;
    node *temp = array[parameter];
    array[parameter] = malloc(sizeof(node));
    array[parameter] -> next = temp;
    array[parameter] -> str = getString();
}

char *getString(void)
{
    char *line = NULL, *tmp = NULL;
    size_t size = 0, index = 0;
    int ch = EOF;

    while (ch)
    {
        ch = getc(stdin);

        /* Check if we need to stop. */
        if (ch == EOF || ch == '\n')
            ch = 0;

        /* Check if we need to expand. */
        if (size <= index)
        {
            size += CHUNK;
            tmp = realloc(line, size);
            if (!tmp)
            {

                free(line);
                line = NULL;
                break;
            }
            line = tmp;
        }

        /* Actually store the thing. */
        line[index++] = ch;
    }

    return line;
}
```

Comment: How doesn't it work as expected?

Comment: After it accepts proper parameter the program crushes out. There must be a problem in push function because getString is a function i found somewhere and it worked properly in my other programs.

Comment: 0) `typedef struct` --> `typedef struct node`

Comment: 1) `initialise` return array;` .. `heads=initialise(heads, no_of_heads);` or `initialise( node **array` --> `initialise( node ***array`. also `array[(*amount_of_lists) - 1]->next = NULL;`

Comment: sory but i didn't understand anything but: array[(*amount_of_lists) - 1]->next = NULL;
Could you please write full sentences with some explenation? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `array[parameter] -> next = temp;` at `push`. Mark for the end of the list is necessary

Comment: or `array[(*amount_of_lists) - 1] = malloc(sizeof(node));` at `initialise` change to `array[(*amount_of_lists) - 1] = NULL;`

Comment: Use a debugger to help you find the cause of your crash.

Comment: See also [Copy the linked list pointed by a parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30695350/copy-the-linked-list-pointed-by-a-parameter).  This isn't a duplicate of that, or vice versa, but they are closely related.

Answer (score 0):

As BLUEPIXY somewhat crypticly hinted at in his comment 1), in order to modify `main()`'s `heads` in `initialise()`, you have to pass `heads` *by reference* to `initialise()`, i. e. change

```
    initialise(heads, no_of_heads);
    initialise(heads, no_of_heads);
```

to

```
    initialise(&heads, no_of_heads);
    initialise(&heads, no_of_heads);
```

consequently

```
node *initialise( node **array, int *amount_of_lists )
```

changes to

```
node *initialise(node ***array, int *amount_of_lists)
```

and inside `array` changes to `*array`, i. e.

```
    *array = realloc(*array, sizeof(node *) * *amount_of_lists);
    return (*array)[*amount_of_lists - 1] = malloc(sizeof(node));
```