# Copy the linked list pointed by a parameter

Tags: c, list, copy, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to implement a function which will make a copy of the list pointed by parameter. I store head pointers to nodes in some array and the parameter is just its index. This is my attempt:

```
void copy(node **array, int *amount_of_lists, int parameter)
{
    node *current = array[parameter];
    array[(*amount_of_lists) - 1] = malloc(sizeof(node));
    node *new_list = array[(*amount_of_lists) - 1];

        while(current->next != NULL)
        {
            new_list->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
            new_list->str = current->str;
            current = current->next;
            new_list = new_list->next;
        }
}
```

Before I call copy function I allocate memory for new the head pointer in mentioned array (last index (amount of lists - 1)). Unfortunately, something is wrong in this function; does anyone know what should it look like?

Comment: How do you know something is wrong?  How does the wrongness manifest itself?  What does running the code under [`valgrind`](http://www.valgrind.org/) say?  Ideally, you should create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) to show what goes wrong.  It needn't be very much longer than the code you show.  (There's at least room for suspicion that either the calling code is at fault, or the `-1` in the array index is dubious.)

Comment: See also [Linked list operations with parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686400/linked-lists-operations-with-parameter).  Same OP, related but slightly different question.  There is no `copy()` function in the other, but there are traits in common (`array[(*amount_of_lists)-1]` was the giveaway).  (Paul — FYI: 'amount' is used in English for continuous quantities, like amount of gold or amount of water; here, you would normally use 'number' for a discrete, countable object type, instead of 'amount'.  Using 'number of water' wouldn't make sense, but 'number of lists' is orthodox.)